# css image file containing many smaller images

Tags: css

I'm a real noob with css and have seen many times, many little icons in a larger file. I'd like to know if I can use something like this for a rating system that I'm making. 5 stars being the best and one being the worst. I'd like to be able to use a single file that contains all of the stars and then based on the rating, show the proper rating. I'm used to doing it the old way by slicing up the images and then showing the rating that way.

What is this and where can I find more info on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a technique known as CSS sprites. The main advantage is that you save some (or sometimes, a lot) of HTTP requests.

You can read about them [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), for example, and one good article to read is also this one on [diagonal CSS sprites](http://www.aaronbarker.net/2010/07/diagonal-sprites/).

When you come to building your own, there's a lot of tools around that will assemble smaller pictures for you and also generate matching CSS with the proper `background-position` values.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for CSS sprites - here's a decent intro

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

and SpriteMe is is a funky little bookmarklet that does the heavy lifting of creating the sprite image for you

http://spriteme.org/

Both links point in turn to other reading for you

Answer (score 0):

It's called [css sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

Answer (score 0):

its called "**[css sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/)**"  look on this article, with example how to do it to rating image:

http://www.last-child.com/image-sprites-flexible-and-accessible-packages/